# capistranoでデプロイ完了後、リモートサーバにあるunicornを立ち上がるためには、何かコマンドが必要なのか？？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

capistranoを使って、nguni＋unicorn＋railsにデプロイしたところ、うまくデプロイが完了しているようなのですが、unicornの画面が立ち上がりません。デプロイ状況の出力（下記参照）を見ると、unicornがkillされてるせいなのか？と思いました。
　そこで、deploy：finishedの後に「unicornのrestart」を行なうように設定し直しましたが、こちらもダメでした。
　確認のためにリモートサーバーのに入って、`ps aus | grep unicorn`で確認したところ、unicornはたちあがっているようです。
　capistranoのログに出てくるkillって何なんでしょうか？それと、ローカルサーバーから何故unicornの画面が確認できないんでしょうか？（何か必要なコマンドがあるのでしょうか？）

●デプロイの出力の最後付近の状況

> 00:12 deploy:symlink:release
>         01 ln -s /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180613094719 /var/www/awesome-events/releases/current
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s
>         02 mv /var/www/awesome-events/releases/current /var/www/awesome-events
>       ✔ 02 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s
>   00:12 unicorn:start
>         unicorn is running...
>         unicorn restarting...
>         01 kill -s USR2 `cat /var/www/awesome-events/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.012s
>   00:12 deploy:cleanup
>         Keeping 5 of 6 deployed releases on vagrant.local
>         01 rm -rf /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180612225508
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.084s
>   00:12 deploy:log_revision
>         01 echo "Branch master (at 7c8fc0327d226c2c847e04285d417535d2f9baee) deployed as release 20180613094719 by takashi_kageyama" >> /var/www/awesom…
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s

●上記のデプロイ時のconfig/deploy.rb

> lock "~> 3.10.2"
>   set :application, "awesome_events"
>   set :repo_url, "https://github.com/takakag/awesome_events.git"
>   set :deploy_to, "/var/www/awesome-events"
>   set :keep_releases, 5
>   set :default_env, {
>           rbenv_root: '/home/ops/.rbenv',
>           path: '/home/ops/.rbenv/shims:/home/ops/.rbenv/bin:$PATH'
>   }
>   set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs,[]).push('tmp/pids')
>   set :unicorn_rack_env, "none"
>   set :unicorn_config_path, 'config/unicorn.rb'
>   after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
>   namespace :deploy do
>     task :restart do
>       invoke 'unicorn:restart'
>     end 
>   end

●上記のconifg/deploy.rbの下から６行目を以下のとおり修正して、デプロイしみる。

> after 'deploy:finished', 'deploy:restart'

→デプロイの結果（最後は、killで終わっている。）

> 00:09 deploy:assets:backup_manifest
>         01 mkdir -p /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180613102301/assets_manifest_backup
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s
>         02 cp /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180613102301/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-06c576762cc73a488eb99cae15076b29.json /var/www/awesome-…
>       ✔ 02 ops@vagrant.local 0.011s
>   00:09 deploy:migrate
>         [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
>   00:09 deploy:migrating
>         01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 1.882s
>   00:11 deploy:symlink:release
>         01 ln -s /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180613102301 /var/www/awesome-events/releases/current
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s
>         02 mv /var/www/awesome-events/releases/current /var/www/awesome-events
>       ✔ 02 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s
>   00:11 deploy:cleanup
>         Keeping 5 of 6 deployed releases on vagrant.local
>         01 rm -rf /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180613092838
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.079s
>   00:11 deploy:log_revision
>         01 echo "Branch master (at 7c8fc0327d226c2c847e04285d417535d2f9baee) deployed as release 20180613102301 by takashi_kageyama" >> /var/www/awesom…
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.009s
>   00:11 unicorn:start
>         unicorn is running...
>         unicorn restarting...
>         01 kill -s USR2 `cat /var/www/awesome-events/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
>       ✔ 01 ops@vagrant.local 0.016s

unicornの接続確認結果

> ops@ubuntu-14:~$ lsof -i
>   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>   ruby    15311  ops    8u  IPv4  46505      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
>   ruby    15320  ops    8u  IPv4  46505      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
>   ruby    15324  ops    8u  IPv4  46505      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
>   ops@ubuntu-14:~$ ps -aux |grep unicorn
>   ops      15311  0.1  7.9 265072 81048 ?        Sl   10:58   0:01 unicorn master -c config/unicorn.rb -E none -D                                                   
>   ops      15320  0.0  7.5 266100 76420 ?        Sl   10:58   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -c config/unicorn.rb -E none -D                                                
>   ops      15324  0.0  7.5 266100 76420 ?        Sl   10:58   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -c config/unicorn.rb -E none -D                                                
>   ops      15465  0.0  0.0  11744   920 pts/1    S+   11:21   0:00 grep --color=auto unicorn

curl localhost:3000の実効結果

```html
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '16.04.4 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Mon Jun 18 22:53:20 2018 from 10.0.2.2
ops@ubuntu-14:~$ curl localhost:3000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AwesomeEvents</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-1c377ed8d3bda9e32406b2ac529612d55b8d1cbe834b36be890686fbf8ad4d9f.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <script src="/assets/application-8d774a7a7b28ba38899760306a48ae0ae90898e49be7fb3b365fe604327f9f77.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="n9PBnBwJHQJg9jnrrs7jkz1xlhvaTmBpy5MpvfQr13A8VX34HM1otVNEPdatqo/KTdD+J8RCLhfczihQ37KleA==" />
  </head>

  <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AwesomeEvents</a>
     </div>
     <div class="cllapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" %>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                <li><a href="/events/new">イベントを作る</a></li>
  <li><a href="/auth/twitter">twitterからログイン</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 
 <div class="container">
 
    <h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
<div class="page-header">
　　<h1>イベント一覧</h1>
</div>
<form class="well" id="event_search" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="q_name_cont">イベント名</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="q[name_cont]" id="q_name_cont" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="q_start_time_gteq">開催日</label>
    <div>
      <select id="q_start_time_gteq_1i" name="q[start_time_gteq(1i)]">
<option value="">年</option>
<option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
</select>
<select id="q_start_time_gteq_2i" name="q[start_time_gteq(2i)]">
<option value="">月</option>
<option value="1">1月</option>
<option value="2">2月</option>
<option value="3">3月</option>
<option value="4">4月</option>
<option value="5">5月</option>
<option value="6" selected="selected">6月</option>
<option value="7">7月</option>
<option value="8">8月</option>
<option value="9">9月</option>
<option value="10">10月</option>
<option value="11">11月</option>
<option value="12">12月</option>
</select>
<select id="q_start_time_gteq_3i" name="q[start_time_gteq(3i)]">
<option value="">日</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19" selected="selected">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
〜
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="検索" class="btn btn-default" data-disable-with="検索" />
</form>
<div class="list-group">
  
</div>

 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のログの意味ですが、USR2シグナルをunicornのプロセスに送っています。
unicornは、USR2シグナルで再起動するみたいですので、 "deploy:restart の結果、USR2シグナルを送って再起動するよ"という意味だと思います。

```
kill -s USR2 cat /var/www/awesome-events/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
```

また、問題切りわけのためには、各ソフトウェアの境界別に確認をする必要があると思います。

```
(1)WEBサーバ =>  (2)unicorn => (3)rails
```

(2)unicornの部分で、unicornプロセスの起動は確認されているということですので、
deployしたサーバーにログインし、
unicornがlistenしているポート(githubをみるかぎりは,127.0.0.1:3000)にアクセス(curlなどで)して
正しくrails appが表示されるか確認してはどうでしょうか？

表示できるようであれば、 (1)・(2)間の接続に問題があると思います。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。「kill -s USR2・・・」は、そういう意味だったのですね。。nginxの設定に問題がありそうなことが、だんだん分かってきました。nginxについては、勉強してみます。

Comment: nginxに問題あるは見当たらないような気がします。コメントにあったとおり、curl 試してみました。helle.html というファイルを作って、「curl -T helle.html http:127.0.0.1:3000」を実行したところ、「curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused」となり、接続できませんでした。ポート関連に問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 境界別に切り分けが必要です。unicornが動いているOSにログインして、netstatなどで127.0.0.1:3000ポートをリッスンしているか確認してはどうでしょうか? (参考: https://qiita.com/sonoshou/items/cc2b740147ba1b8da1f3)

Comment: なるほどです。unicornはlistenしてました。やっぱり、nginxの設定が悪いという事になるんでしょうか。（結果を本文中に追記しました）

Comment: unicornはちゃんと起動しているみたいですね。 (2)(3)間の接続切り分けのために、unicornが動いているOSにログインして、"curl http://localhost:3000" を実行してみてください。htmlが表示されれば(2)(3)間に問題はないと思います。表示されなければ、unicornやrailsのログを確認して問題を切り分ける必要があります。

Comment: おお〜。"curl  localhost:3000"の実効結果追記しました。こんな画面ですね。。やっぱり、nginxのchefの設定がおかしいようです。問題が絞り込めてきました。ありがとうございます。「chef supermarket」からダウンロードした"nginx"の cookbookがよく分からなくて、苦戦していますが・・・。（とほほ。。。）